# Обьясните, что делает этот код

Tags: java, android, gradle

Я уже давно занимаюсь одним проектом и в процессе разработки добавлял строки в градл и вот сейчас просматривал градл и заметил кусок кода

```
android {

...

sourceSets {
    main {
        dirs.each { dir ->
            java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
            res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
        }
    }
    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
}
}
```

В нем `.srcDirs` выделяется серым и говорит, что не может распознать что это такое...

А я вообще не могу вспомнить, что этот кусок кода делает.

Можете подсказать кто разбирается с градл файлами?

Comment: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520403/android-instrumentation-tests-в-папке-androidtest-java-не-удается-создать-класс

Comment: @user186301 все равно мне тяжело понять, что в итоге делает этот кусок кода...

Comment: Тут не задают таких вопросов. Тут решают конкретные проблемы. Какая у вас проблема?

Comment: @metalurgus ну я не уверен, что это проблема. Просто болтается в градле этот кусок кода и я вот не пойму,что он делает)

Answer (score 6):

блок `sourceSets` определяет сеты исходных файлов, которые группируются в группы, например `main`. Внутри этих групп ты создаешь директории исходников для разных типов файлов (плагины их ожидают найти). В данном случае у тебя есть 2 директории - java файлы пойдут в `src/main/java`, ресурсы пойдут в `src/main/res`.

Эти блоки обычно добавляют сами плагины, и тебе нет необходимости их писать, кроме случаев, когда ты хочешь изменить значения по умолчанию, как в данном случае, изменив `src/main/resources` на `src/main/res`.

Comment: а почему идея показывает, что не распознает  `.srcDirs`? И если я правильно понял, то можно ее удалить?

Comment: Idea не знает, что такое `java` в данном контексте, это динамически resolvable поле в рантайме. Соответсвенно, Idea понятия не имеет, какие у этого поля есть properties. Удалить нельзя, потому что наверняка что-то где-то завязано на то, что resources называются `res`, а не стандартно - `resources`. P.S. если ответ правильный, то accept будет не лишним.

Comment: вообще для андройда стандартно как раз `res` а не а не `resources`

Comment: А, ну тогда можно стереть, да

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko чего там с ацептом? :)

Comment: Я первый раз прочитал не правильно, а что вы имеете ввиду под accept?

Comment: accept the answer if it's correct. Галочка зелененькая :)